# play sound in method when the method have a multiple calls

Tags: objective-c

I need to play a keyboard sound effect when user touch in button.

but the problem is when the user tap 3 time in the button the

playTypingSound method call 3 time but I hear the typing sound effect once.

I do not want to use Apple's keyboard sound

This is My method:

```
-(void)playTypingSound
{
NSURL *soundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"typing" ofType:@"mp3"]];
typingSound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL error:nil];
typingSound.volume = 0.05;
[typingSound play];
}
```

http://puu.sh/gBhKF/2f271d8804.png

Comment: I edit the question , the duration is 00:00

Comment: @property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *typingSound;

Comment: Then it should work perfectly. Code is correct. I think something wrong with your sound file

Comment: if I tap very fast in button I hear the sound only in last tap.

Comment: I check with some sounds I have in My project and the problem continues.

Comment: @RoeiNadam: Were you able to fix your problem?